# Given a monotone decreasing fuction $f$ prove that $f(x) \ln2 \leq \int^{2x}_x f(t)/t dt \leq f(2x) \ln 2 $ for all $x<0$

Tags: integration

Let $f:(-\infty, 0) \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function with $f'<0 \; \forall x<0$. Prove that $$f(x) \ln2 \leq \int^{2x}_x \frac {f(t)} t dt \leq f(2x) \ln 2 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f' < 0$ for all $x < 0$, $f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$. Therefore, on $[x,2x]$, $f(2x) \le f(t) \le f(x)$. Thus $f(x)/t \le f(t)/t \le f(2x)/t$ on $[x,2x]$, and consequently

$$\int_x^{2x} \frac{f(x)}{t}\, dt \le \int_x^{2x} \frac{f(t)}{t} \, dt \le \int_x^{2x} \frac{f(2x)}{t}\, dt.$$

That is,

$$f(x)\ln 2 \le \int_x^{2x} \frac{f(t)}{t}\, dx \le f(2x)\ln 2.$$